# stunnel with TLS for POP3 and SMTP: config is?

Tags: stunnel

Have used stunnel successfully for years over SSLv3.  Simple config works with older stunnel and SSLv3:

```
[noteworthypop]
accept  = 110
connect = secure.emailsrvr.com:995

[noteworthysmtp]
accept = 25
connect = secure.emailsrvr.com:465
```

However, this config is not working for me now that rackspace shut off SSL v3.

We updated to the current stunnel (5.07), which has TLS support. We run stunnel on a windows 2008 server.

Above conf does not work.
Adding protocol lines makes no difference. E.g.

```
[noteworthypop]
client = yes
accept  = 110
connect = secure.emailsrvr.com:995
protocol = pop3

[noteworthysmtp]
client = yes
accept = 25
connect = secure.emailsrvr.com:465
protocol = smtp
```

When attempting pop, the log shows:

```
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG7[2800]: Service [noteworthypop] accepted (FD=356) from 192.168.110.203:62058
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG7[2800]: Creating a new thread
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG7[2800]: New thread created
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG7[3232]: Service [noteworthypop] started
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG5[3232]: Service [noteworthypop] accepted connection from 192.168.110.203:62058
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG6[3232]: s_connect: connecting 98.129.185.2:465
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG7[3232]: s_connect: s_poll_wait 98.129.185.2:465: waiting 10 seconds
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG5[3232]: s_connect: connected 98.129.185.2:465
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG5[3232]: Service [noteworthypop] connected remote server from 192.168.97.23:62960
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG7[3232]: Remote socket (FD=360) initialized
2014.11.06 14:25:01 LOG7[3232]: RFC 2595 detected
```

But it sits. The pop client gets no action, nothing happens.

Suggestions welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: Try lots of things until something works.

The "protocol" entry actually broke things.

This works:

```
[noteworthypop]
client = yes
accept = 110
connect = secure.emailsrvr.com:995


[noteworthysmtp]
client = yes
accept = 25
connect = secure.emailsrvr.com:465
```